# Matlab assign values on specific elements of matrix

Tags: matlab

How can I do this more general?

`XD_L` array is manual introduce.

```
% Data
Xd_L = [10 100 1000];
C = zeros(length(Xd_L))

% Calc
C12 = -1/Xd_L(1);
C13 = -1/Xd_L(2);
C11 = abs(C12+C13);

C21 = C12;
C23 = -1/Xd_L(3);
C22 = abs(C21+C23);

C31 = C13;
C32 = C23;
C33 = abs(C31+C32);

% Result:
C = [C11 C12 C13; C21 C22 C23; C31 C32 C33]
```

Comment: What do you mean by _more general_? what is the purpose of this code?

Comment: something like: `for i =1:length(Xd_L)` and `for j =1:length(Xd_L)` `C(i,j)=`

Comment: I want more general because in my case the matrix C have 23x23 dimension, and for determinate the elements of C I need to write 529 formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach for a generic case -

```
function out = scale_assign(Xd_L)

m = numel(Xd_L);
n = ceil(sqrt(2*m));
off_diag_vals = -1./Xd_L;
[y,x] = find(tril(true(n),-1));

out = zeros(n,n);
out(sub2ind(size(out),y,x)) = off_diag_vals;
out(sub2ind(size(out),x,y)) = off_diag_vals;
out(1:n+1:n^2) = abs(sum(out,2));
```

Sample runs -

```
>> Xd_L = [10 100 1000];
>> scale_assign(Xd_L)
ans =
         0.11         -0.1        -0.01
         -0.1        0.101       -0.001
        -0.01       -0.001        0.011
>> Xd_L = [10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000];
>> scale_assign(Xd_L)
ans =
        0.111         -0.1        -0.01       -0.001
         -0.1      0.10011      -0.0001       -1e-05
        -0.01      -0.0001     0.010101       -1e-06
       -0.001       -1e-05       -1e-06     0.001011
```

Comment: @Marius If I understood correctly, the number of elements in `Xd_L` has to be specific numbers, that are obtained from `size(nchoosek(1:M,2),1)`, where M is the size of the output matrix. Thus, those specific numbers would be : `3`, `6`, `10` , `15` and so on. Does that make sense or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: For exemple if: `Xd_L=[8.40 4.80 5.2 5.6 10 6.4 10.8 7.2 4.8 8.8 14 6.8];` it doesn't work. That means my output matrix have 12x12 dimension

Comment: @Marius What's the expected size of the output matrix from that `Xd_L`?

Comment: The size of the output matrix is 12x12

Comment: @Marius I am not sure how you would be getting that. How about use a smaller sample with `Xd_L` having say 4 elements and show us the expected output?

Comment: When I run:  `Xd_L = [10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000];`  the output it's good, but if i add an extra element in `Xd_L` he give me error.

Comment: @Marius Let me say again - Use a smaller sample with Xd_L having say 4 elements and show us the expected output. Edit the question to add these.

Comment: You are right, here is the problem, i'm not sure what is the output, i will make a little search and after that i will post another question.